# Is my logic about comparing the 70th/90th percentile from two respective datasets correct or is there a proof to do this?

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, median, order-statistics, percentage

> Larry and Tony work for different companies. Larry's salary is the $90th$ percentile of the salaries in his company, and Tony`s salary is the $70th$ percentile of the salaries in his company.

> Which of the following statements individually provide(s) sufficient additional information to conclude that Larry`s salary is higher than Tony's salary?
> Indicate all such statements.

> 1. The average (arithmetic mean) salary in Larry's company is higher
>    than the average salary in Tony's company

> 2. The median salary in Larry's company is equal to the median salary
>    in Tony`s company

> 3. The $80th$ percentile in Larry's company is higher than
>    the $70th$ percentile salary in Tony's company

The hand-wavy logic I had was that the median is too far from the 80th/90th percentile to indicate anything. The average includes too many order statistics for us to tell about the 90th and 70th percentile which are too very possibly different statistics than any order statistic besides those two.

What's a more rigorous logic to solve this problem?

Comment: You have a good argument going for why 1 and 2 are *not* correct. I would recommend providing a counterexample for each of 1 and 2, i.e., salary structures that satisfy 1, but Larry earns less than Tony, and another example for 2. Finally, can you provide an argument why 3 is correct (other than that 1 and 2 are wrong)?

Comment: If your logic is correct, it should help you find specific counterexamples in which (1) and (2) are false.  (You could even look for a *single* counterexample in which (1) and (2) are *both* false.)  Ultimately, a rigorous full explanation would appeal to the *definitions* of percentiles and arithmetic means.